# Can we make prediction with nlxb from nlmrt package?

Tags: r, dplyr, pipeline, nls

I'm asking this question because I couldn't figure it out why `nlxb` fitting function does not work with the predict() function.

I have been looking around to solve this but so far no luck:(

I use `dplyr` to group data and use `do` to fit each group using `nlxb` from `nlmrt` package.

Here is my attempt

```
set.seed(12345)
set =rep(rep(c("1","2","3","4"),each=21),times=1)
time=rep(c(10,seq(100,900,100),seq(1000,10000,1000),20000),times=1)
value <- replicate(1,c(replicate(4,sort(10^runif(21,-6,-3),decreasing=FALSE))))
data_rep <- data.frame(time, value,set)

> head(data_rep)
    #    time        value set
    #1     10 1.007882e-06   1
    #2    100 1.269423e-06   1
    #3    200 2.864973e-06   1
    #4    300 3.155843e-06   1
    #5    400 3.442633e-06   1
    #6    500 9.446831e-06   1
    *      *       *         *  

library(dplyr)
library(nlmrt)

    d_step <- 1
    f <- 1e9
    d <- 32      
    formula = value~Ps*(1-exp(-2*f*time*exp(-d)))*1/(sqrt(2*pi*sigma))*exp(-(d-d_ave)^2/(2*sigma))*d_step

      dffit = data_rep %>% group_by(set) %>%
      do(fit = nlxb(formula ,
                    data = .,
                    start=c(d_ave=44,sigma=12,Ps=0.5),
                    control=nls.lm.control(maxiter = 100),
                    trace=TRUE))
```

## --------------------------------------------------------

There are two points I would like to get finally,

1)First, how to get fitting coefficients of each group in continuation to `dffit`pipeline.

2) Doing prediction of based on new x values.

for instance `range <- data.frame(x=seq(1e-5,20000,length.out=10000))`

predict(fit,data.frame(x=range)

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "nlmrt"
```

Since `nlxb` is working smoothly compared to `nls` [r-minpack-lmnls-lm-failed-with-good-results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35409099/r-minpack-lmnls-lm-failed-with-good-results/35516421#35516421)  I would prefer solutions with `nlxb`. But if you have a better solution please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

There are no `coef` or `predict` methods for `"nlmrt"` class objects but the nlmrt package does provide `wrapnls` which will run `nlmrt` and then `nls` so that an `"nls"` object results and then that object can be used with all the `"nls"` class methods.

Also note that `nls.lm.control` is from the nlsLM package and should not be used here -- use `list` instead.

Comment: thank you for your advice. I will let you know after checking  `wrapnls`.

Comment: I checked `wrapnls` and fitting does not converge and getting singular gradient error. Did you see my newest post [failed-to-do-fitting-several-attempts-with-nls-nlxb-and-wrapnls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133471/failed-to-do-fitting-several-attempts-with-nls-nlxb-and-wrapnls)